# create an empty table which gets the column names from another table

Tags: kdb

We have two tables 't' and 's'.
These tables may or may not have data but the schema of both t and s will alwaya be same.

```
Tables:
q)t:([] id:("ab";"cd";"ef";"gh";"ij"); refid:("";"ab";"";"ef";""); typ:`BUY`SELL`BUY`SELL`BUY)
q)s:t / For example purpose
```

Now, in my function. I want to concatenate the output of these two tables and return it, for which I'm using variable named res.

The problem is initially res is empty and not of type 98h, hence if I try to join t or s to res then it fails(which is obvious).

```
q){$[not ((count res) ~ 0); res: res,t ; res:t ]; $[not ((count res) ~ 0); res: res,s ; res:s ]; :res}[]
'res
```

One solution to this is create an empty schema for res(same as t and s table) and it works perfectly.

```
q){res:([] id:(); refid:(); typ:`$());$[not ((count res) ~ 0); res: res,t ; res:t ]; $[not ((count res) ~ 0); res: res,s ; res:s ]; :res}[]
```

But, is there a way that we don't have to create empty schema for res with all columns before hand, rather assign res as null(empty) table which can get the schema same as t or s when t or s is joined with res.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want to just use `res:t,s`?

Comment: yes, because in my complete code data res is being used and massaged and filtered before returning the res data from function.

Comment: if res is already an existing variable, then it sounds like you definitely won't want to redefine it as an empty table, no?

Comment: No, res is not an existing variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example isn't entirely clear - you mention `res` already exists in a comment, but then state that "initially res is empty and not of type 98h".

If you only want to assign res to be an empty table if it doesn't already exist, you can use a system command to check if res has already been defined in the root namespace, like the below:

```
f:{
  if[not res in system"a";res:()]
  $[count res;res,:t;res:t]; 
  $[count res;res,:s;res:s]; 
  :res;
 };
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. That an empty list can appended with a table.'res:()' was what I wanted to understand.

Comment: `system` calls can often be restricted by permissioning and will prevent multithreading. A better way to check if it is defined is ```()~key `res ```. It will also often be a faster action.

Answer (score 0):

Assign res to be 0 take the schema in question.

```
q)t:([] id:("ab";"cd";"ef";"gh";"ij"); refid:("";"ab";"";"ef";""); typ:`BUY`SELL`BUY`SELL`BUY)
q)res:0#t
q)meta res
c    | t f a
-----| -----
id   |
refid|
typ  | s
```

So in this case you can do the following

```
q){[]res:0#t;if[count res;res,:t];$[count res;res,:s;res:s]}[]
```